# What is a "censorship visa"?

Tags: film-industry, censorship

While perusing the trivia notes of movies on IMDB, I occasionally see something like the following (from [Sabrina (1995)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114319/trivia/?ref_=tt_trv_trv)):

> Italian censorship visa # 90717 delivered on 29 February 1996.

Most of the time it's an Italian censorship visa that's listed. Occasionally I've seen a German censorship visa. In an effort to understand what these are, I found that they are occasionally used to provide statistical or specific data about a movie.

What I couldn't find, to a degree that was quite surprising, was any information about what a "censorship visa" is, why it's issued, and how it's issued.

What is a "censorship visa"?

Extra gratitude if either some history, or a link to some history, can be provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> visto nm.
> visa, check, authorization, official permission

https://italian.yabla.com/define/visto

> Per saperne di più:
> Il modulo domanda di revisione viene compilato dalla società di produzione o distribuzione del film e presentato alla Direzione Generale per il Cinema. Successivamente la Commissione di Censura visiona il film ed emette, con apposito Decreto di prima istanza, il suo giudizio che può essere favorevole, sfavorevole o condizionato (ovvero la pubblica visione è condizionata alla eliminazione di parti del film o vietata a un pubblico di età inferiore a 14, 16, 18 anni). Con la concessione del nulla osta alla proiezione in pubblico, apposto sulla domanda di Revisione si genera il cosiddetto **visto di censura** e la pellicola può essere distribuita in sala.
> Nel caso in cui la Commissione emetta un giudizio condizionato (limiti d'età o tagli), la società di produzione o distribuzione ha due possibilità: eseguire le modifiche, inviando comunicazione alla DG Cinema e successivamente copia del film modificato per il quale verrà indicato il nuovo metraggio sul **visto censura**. In alternativa, la società ha la possibilità, attraverso lettera di ricorso, di richiedere il Giudizio di Appello di seconda istanza. La Commissione di revisione di secondo grado può, con apposito Decreto di seconda istanza, confermare il giudizio di prima istanza o emettere un giudizio nuovo. In ogni caso questo giudizio sarà definitivo.
> Accade spesso, nel caso di giudizio negativo della Commissione di secondo grado, che la società apporti rilevanti modifiche al film e lo ripresenti con una nuova domanda di revisione alla DG Cinema. In questo caso, il **visto di censura** avrà un numero diverso e verosimilmente un metraggio inferiore.

http://www.italiataglia.it/bancadati [bolding added]

Google translate:

> To find out more:
> The review application form is filled in by the film's production or distribution company and submitted to the Directorate General for Cinema. Subsequently, the Censorship Commission views the film and issues, with a special first instance Decree, its judgment which can be favorable, unfavorable or conditional (i.e. the public viewing is conditional on the elimination of parts of the film or prohibited to an audience under the age of at 14, 16, 18 years). With the granting of the authorization for public screening, affixed to the Revision application, the so-called **censorship visa** is generated and the film can be distributed in theaters.
> In the event that the Commission issues a conditional judgment (age limits or cuts), the production or distribution company has two options: to make the changes, by sending a communication to DG Cinema and subsequently a copy of the modified film for which the new footage on **visa censorship**. Alternatively, the company has the possibility, through a letter of appeal, to request the second instance Appeal Judgment. The second instance audit commission may, with a specific second instance decree, confirm the first instance judgment or issue a new judgment. In any case, this judgment will be final.
> It often happens, in the case of a negative judgment of the second degree commission, that the company makes significant changes to the film and presents it with a new review request to DG Cinema. In this case, the **censorship visa** will have a different number and likely less footage.

You can learn more here: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censura_cinematografica_(Italia) (Italian language wikipedia).

Comment: This answer would be greatly enhanced with a summary that states this is a term used for official passing of a movie for screening, part of the process of film classification / censorship.